# ¿Por qué no se agrega una imagen con DocumentFragment?

Tags: javascript, filereader

Si utilizo `imagesContainer.appendChild(img)` si me agrega las imagenes, pero con el fragmento no, ¿alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

```
const leerArchivo =  ar =>{
    for(let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(ar[i]);
        reader.addEventListener("load",(e)=>{
            const img = document.createElement("IMG");
            img.id = `img-${i+1}`;
            img.src = e.target.result;
            fragment.appendChild(img);
        });
    };
};
imagesContainer.appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema en este caso puede ser que el código que agrega las imágenes al DOM se está ejecutando de manera asíncrona dentro del evento "load" del objeto FileReader. Esto significa que el código que agrega las imágenes al contenedor está siendo llamado antes de que se completen todas las lecturas de archivos y la construcción del fragmento.

Para solucionar este problema, puedes crear una promesa para que el código espere a que se completen todas las lecturas de archivos antes de agregar el fragmento al contenedor. Aquí te muestro un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:

```
const leerArchivo =  async ar =>{
    const promises = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(ar[i]);
        const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
            reader.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
                const img = document.createElement("IMG");
                img.id = `img-${i+1}`;
                img.src = e.target.result;
                resolve(img);
            });
        });
        promises.push(promise);
    };
    const images = await Promise.all(promises);
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    images.forEach((img) => fragment.appendChild(img));
    imagesContainer.appendChild(fragment);
};
```

En este ejemplo, creamos un array de promesas para cada lectura de archivo, y resolvemos cada promesa dentro del evento "load" del objeto FileReader. Después de crear todas las promesas, usamos la función "Promise.all" para esperar a que se completen todas las promesas y devolver un array con todas las imágenes. Luego, creamos un fragmento y agregamos todas las imágenes a él usando un forEach. Finalmente, agregamos el fragmento completo al contenedor de imágenes.